# ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'dataTables/src/demo_table_jui'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am trying to show a paginated list of results back from a database and have ended up looking at using dataTables.  I have been following rails cast 340 but hit a problem with the above error.  I am running rails 3.1.12.

My files are as follows:
Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.12'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem "less-rails"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'savon', '2.5.1'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
//= require_tree .
```

application.cs

```
*= require_self
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
*= require_tree .
```

nettica.coffee.js

```
jQuery ->
  $('#domains').dataTable
      sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
```

Any ideas?

Further on down the line I also get problems with adding:

```
      bJQueryUI: true
```

to the above file.

Thank you

Comment: Try `//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables`, looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) they have changed what the js file is called

Comment: I changed the application.js file to use that instead but now I get :

Comment: Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /vagrant/codelearn/nettica/tmp/cache/sass/f0510e618e621a14233122162fef6d27efc6dc16/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x000000036c7660>
Compiled dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.css  (71ms)  (pid 10123)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9395ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `dependency_paths' for #<Sprockets::StaticAsset:0x00000005b1e220>):
    3: <head>

Comment: forgot to say thank you Baloo for taking the time to reply

Comment: Documentation says to use `//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap` in application.js if using bootstrap and add `*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap` in application.css

Comment: I still get the same dependency_path error after adding them in :(